# MS Native unit test - Assert::Fail from a thread won't work

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-c++, mstest

Sample code:

```
TEST_CLASS(MyTests)
{    
    TEST_METHOD(MT_Test)
    {
          std::thread t([]() 
          {              
             Assert::Fail(L"Failure!");
          });

          t.join();
     }    
};
```

When `MT_Test` is run/debug, it never says that the test failed due to test assertion failure. Varied behaviors on different runs or on different VS versions (2017/2019):

- Test succeeds (green tick)
- Test becomes inconclusive (blue exclamation)
- MS Test engine crashes

But not a single time, the test failure occurs.

How to propagate/render such failure from a thread?

Answer (score 2):

As per [CppUnitTestFramework: Testrunner crashed by Assert statements in a thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/301695/cppunittestframework-testrunner-crashed-by-assert.html),

> Let me get this straight: The framework is not designed for checking
> test conditions (assertions) in threads?
>
> Unfortunately no, the C++ test framework assumes that exceptions
> thrown by Asserts would be on the same thread.